# Is there a way to find out all the Activity Names that were associated to a particular Package after that package is removed?

Tags: android-intent

NOTE : till now I have only been able to find out the packageName using the action Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED and using getData().getSchemeSpecificPart() on the intent

Searching for the UID returns error and trying to pull out corresponding PackageInfo also throws NameNotFoundException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a NO way out. Unless and Until you deliberately save the package names and their corresponding activities some where in the Storage and later on get them using the retrieved package name from the intent and then searching through the previously stored package-activities list.